# Can't access PPP equipment connected to VMWare Guest

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, lubuntu, ppp, pppd

Well, basically, what I'm trying to do is to connect an equipment that needs to talk to a Windows Host through a Linux (Lubuntu) Guest.

Now a bit more of details:

1 - I have a software that only runs on Windows, and this is running on the Windows host that's also running the VMWare Player;

2 - The equipment talks RS-485, and connects using a PPP link, so I'm using a Serial x USB converter

3 - Using pppd on the Guest, I've created a connection to the equipment board that I need to talk to;

4 - From the Guest, I'm able to ping this equipment's remote IP (192.168.2.2), and I can confirm it by the equipment interace board LEDs...

5 - ... But I can't do it from my Windows Host.

6 - From the Host, I can ping the VM NIC (192.168.2.1) and the local PPP IP (192.168.2.4);

7 - The network card is configured with NAT.

8 - This is the command I'm using to create the PPP link: `pppd silent noccp  nodetach noauth local logfile /home/logs/''$timestamp''pppd2.txt nocrtscts defaultroute kdebug 5 debug proxyarp 192.168.2.4:192.168.2.2 /dev/ttyMXUSB2 9600`

Here'a an illustration of my network:
[Network.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjPrN.png)

Do you guys have any idea of what's going on?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your Windows 10 PPP Connection forces all internet traffic through the PPP tunnel . So I do not think your Guest will connect to the tunnel or to the internet.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to disable my Wi-Fi connection to make sure all the traffic would flow through the only active connection (that would be the Virtual NIC), but no success...

Comment: Standard (non-PPP) connections, that is, plain vanilla non-VPN connections should work through the guest and back.

Comment: Yes.. This is why I can't understand what's going on... I'm not using any kind of VPN, everything is local, and to avoid any silly errors, I've put everythin gunder the same network.

Comment: I am working in a VMware Workstation Guest here (Kali Linux) and can access shares on the Host and, of course, the outside world. You might try reinstalling VMware Player (make a backup of your guest) and restart the computer and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've figured out that the IP forwarding was not enabled in Linux VM.

Basically, to make it work, I had to enable it by using: `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Thanks a lot for the sugestions! :D